# Issues completing the displayAvgLongitude function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

I'm having a little trouble with the last step of my homework. The step reads, "Complete the displayAvgLongitude function. It should retrieve the data, sum the values of all the longitudes, divide by the number of elements in the array, and place that single value into the div tag with the id of textDisplayed5". any advice is greatly appreciated

Here is what I've got for that section, I feel like I'm close but its not giving me the correct number when I run it

```
function displayAvgLongitude() { 
    $.getJSON("http://misdemo.temple.edu/states",function(result){
        console.log(result);
        let answer = result[0]["longitude"];
        
        for(let i=0; i < result.length;i++){
            answer= (result[i]['longitude']/result.length)*result.length;
        }
        $('#textDisplayed5').html(answer);
    });
}
```

hope this is enough information

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement you mentioned in the question, Here are steps you have to follow.

- By using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) fetch all the longitude values from the response array and then sum all of those using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.
- Now, You can do this calculation `sum/responsearray.length` and store it in a variable and bind that variable value into the HTML div element.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Just for a demo purpose I am directly using the mock response, You can replace it with an API call and get the data.
const result = [{"state":"AK","latitude":63.588753,"longitude":-154.493062,"state_name":"Alaska"},{"state":"AL","latitude":32.318231,"longitude":-86.902298,"state_name":"Alabama"},{"state":"AR","latitude":35.20105,"longitude":-91.831833,"state_name":"Arkansas"},{"state":"AZ","latitude":34.048928,"longitude":-111.093731,"state_name":"Arizona"},{"state":"CA","latitude":36.778261,"longitude":-119.417932,"state_name":"California"},{"state":"CO","latitude":39.550051,"longitude":-105.782067,"state_name":"Colorado"},{"state":"CT","latitude":41.603221,"longitude":-73.087749,"state_name":"Connecticut"},{"state":"DE","latitude":38.910832,"longitude":-75.52767,"state_name":"Delaware"},{"state":"FL","latitude":27.664827,"longitude":-81.515754,"state_name":"Florida"},{"state":"GA","latitude":32.157435,"longitude":-82.907123,"state_name":"Georgia"}];

// Get all the longitude values in an array.
const longArr = result.map(({ longitude }) => longitude);

// get the sum of all the langitudes and store it in a variable
const sum = longArr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);

const finalCalculation = sum/longArr.length;

document.getElementById('textDisplayed5').innerHTML = finalCalculation;
```

```html
<div id="textDisplayed5"></div>
```